# Preconditioner for circulant matrices?

Tags: numerical-methods, circulant-matrices

I have a circulant matrix and would like to know how I can get good preconditioners for it. How does one usually find such preconditioners and what are good ones for a matrix of such a specific type?

All hints and insights are welcome particularly also hints to specialized literature! Is there lit. about preconditioners of circulant matrices? I checked quite intensively but unfortunately didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: A circulant matrix is diagonalized by the discrete Fourier transform (the eigenvalues are the Fourier coefficients of a row), so it is easy to invert directly (assuming it is invertible).  What do you want a preconditioner for?

Comment: The problem is not that I don't know formally the inverse. The problem is that it is very ill-conditioned, so numerically it is very instable. I want to solve the LSE by some iteration method like Krawzcyk' s and therefore need a suitable preconditioner.

Comment: Well a circulant matrix is a convolution operator.  To apply the inverse, you can take the discrete Fourier transform of the first row, multiply it entry-wise by the discrete Fourier transform of the vector, and then take the inverse discrete Fourier transform.  But if your problem is very ill-conditioned (say, the operator represents convolution by a smooth function like a Gaussian), then there is no hope at getting a suitable inverse regardless of the algorithm.

Comment: What preconditioner would you take in the case that the circulant matrix is not hopelessly ill-conditioned? I am actually interested to find bounds for the needed precision and gain insight into "how hopeless" my matrix is, particularly with respect to the case that the problem (the matrix size) grows.

Comment: Well the condition number is going to be the ratio between the minimum and maximum Fourier coefficient of the thing you're convolving with.  The procedure I described above is an efficient algorithm (NlogN time, if N is dimension of matrix) for inverting the matrix, and it's as stable as possible (given that the Fourier transform is a unitary operator) so there's no need for a preconditioner.